# How to Remove Orbeon Logo Form published forms on storefront?

Tags: forms, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud

[image]

Hi, Currently am working on hybris 6.5. I want to remove Header which have orbeon form logo. I have published forms on storefront.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the logo by setting the [`oxf.fr.default-logo.uri.*.*` property](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#default-logo). This in done in your `properties-local.xml`, and if you haven't gotten a chance to modify that file yet, you might find going through the [doc on properties](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/) useful.